# Is there anyway to get ID3 metadata from an MP3 or Vorbis comments from Ogg via the HTML5 audio element?

Tags: audio, html, metadata, id3, oggvorbis

[Mozilla Developer Center's HTML5 media guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_audio_and_video_in_Firefox#Media_events) describes an event for audio and video elements called "loadedmetadata". Is there anyway to get the metadata for files? I am writing an HTML5 extension for Google Chrome and I don't know what the metadata for the audio files I'm creating a player for beforehand.

Edit: This question seems to be kicking everyone's ass. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/12/w3c-fileapi-in-firefox-3-6/) you can use `filereader.readAsBinaryString(file);` to get the binary data of the ID3 tag.

> filereader.readAsBinaryString(file); will asynchronously return a binary string with each byte represented by an integer in the range [0..255]. This is useful for binary manipulations of a file’s data, for example to look for ID3 tags in an MP3 file, or to look for EXIF data in a JPEG image.

Comment: Hrm, I have to check to see if chrome has this.

Comment: Aha, you are correct on the binary stuff though, this will work:
http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/08/reading-id3-tags-with-javascript.html
but faces cross-domain issues

Comment: Actually filreader will only work with files on the user's computer and I want to work with files on remote servers. I think xhr's have a way to read binary data. I'll use that instead.