# PHP: Class to parse OGG and .ogv files?

Tags: php, class, video, parsing, ogg

I am looking for a php class that can parse ogg and .ogv files so that I can get some of the metadata out of the files, such as comments, bitrate, length, etc.

I have found this: http://opensource.grisambre.net/ogg/ but after testing it, it does not seem to parse and of the files that I test it with.

Has anyone had luck with an alternative?

I would use getID3(), but it does not support ogg video.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used it, but the PEAR [File_Ogg](http://pear.php.net/package/File_Ogg) package might be what you need to use.

Answer (score 0):

Consider JavaScript as the most likely route. This may help: [Is there anyway to get ID3 metadata from an MP3 or Vorbis comments from Ogg via the HTML5 audio element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244806/is-there-anyway-to-get-id3-metadata-from-an-mp3-or-vorbis-comments-from-ogg-via-t)