# Get ID3 Tag from html5 <audio> tag

Tags: html, html5-audio

how can i get ID3 tag from html5  tag that src from other server url.

ID3 tag like album art, title, album title, artist.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244806/is-there-anyway-to-get-id3-metadata-from-an-mp3-or-vorbis-comments-from-ogg-via and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370222/how-to-get-audio-tag-infomation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is close to what you want: https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader

It takes a URL instead of and  object.

Answer (score 2):

To get an ID3 tag from an MP3, the MP3 needs to be decoded -- this isn't available from HTML5s audio tag. There are implementations ([aurora.js](https://github.com/audiocogs/aurora.js), [jsmad](https://github.com/audiocogs/jsmad)) that analyze the file itself and has access to ID3 tags.